# Taking marble out of a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have to boxes, in box number 1 we place 5 white and three black marbles, in box number 2 we place 2 white and 2 black marbles. 10 times in a row we choose one marble out of each box  (5 times from each box), after we have chosen we put them back in a box. Find the probability that at least two marbles were of the same colour.
I want to use Bernoulli's scheme, however i do not know what is the probability of success. Blind guess is that it will be 0.5, but i have no idea whether that's correct and why if it is.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is meant by "after we have chosen we put them back in a box"? Are the marbles placed back in the box they were chosen from, or each placed into one of the boxes at random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2$ let $W_i$ denotes the event that the marble taken form box $i$ is white.

For $i=1,2$ let $B_i$ denotes the event that the marble taken form box $i$ is black.

Then the probability of success is: $$P((W_1\cap W_2)\cup(B_1\cap B_2))=P(W_1\cap W_2)+P(B_1\cap B_2)=P(W_1)P(W_2)+P(B_1)P(B_2)$$